# Is it possible to work without App Delegate?

Tags: objective-c, appdelegate

My question is based on the fact that, one might have multiple smaller projects and then wants to integrate them into one bigger one, for coding efficiency.

I saw multiple project's where the App Delegate wasn't used at all, I think the Adium project was one of them. I also was a couple of times able to recreate it in the past, now I cannot remember how.

I figure a basic NSObject inherited class would fit, plus its instantiation and connections.

The question is, is it possible to work without App Delegate (or have a workaround)?

Comment: Do you mean to not have the AppDelegate at all or to just not add additional code into the AppDelegate?

Comment: I mean having no additional code in AppDelegate

Answer (score 3):

You need an app delegate, if you want to implement some of the methods declared in the [`NSApplicationDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol to respond to certain app life-cycle events. If you don't need to implement any of those, you don't need an app delegate. Some delegate methods also have notification alternatives.

Comment: What would belong to app life-cycle events? Showing a window and having elements interact with each other?

Comment: Check out the documentation I linked. Everything in that protocol has to be implemented in an app delegate. Note that this object can be anything. It's just a protocol (aka interface in some other languages).

Comment: I tried it out, got a basic setup an am not using app delegate but a class instantiated in an object as a 'quasi-delegate', but the code of the class does not get run (breakpoints check)... What could I do now?

Answer (score 2):

OK, from your comment...

```
I mean having no additional code in AppDelegate
```

Then yes.

It is not only possible, it is recommended. Exactly for the reason that you have said.

The app delegate is there as a communication layer between the app and the OS.  i.e. "the app has started", "the app is about to close", "the app just received a notification", etc...

All of these is what the app delegate is for.

The logic of your app should not go anywhere near you app delegate. Like you said, you may have different apps or different targets in your app that use different app delegates.

If you have code in there then you would have to duplicate it to each copy.

There are many other reasons too.

Here is a quick link... http://www.hollance.com/2012/02/dont-abuse-the-app-delegate/

There are many others about not using the app delegate.

Comment: I agree, its is really relevant and important for a lot of reasons, I read that resource as well. Now all I need to figure out is how to make any code executable, because I tried with no AppDelegate setup and via breakpoints I discovered none of my code was being run.

Comment: Mind you a very very basic setup would suffice to show how it would work. Will accept your answer, we're getting close to a solution here!! Thanks @Fogmeister.